# Spring Batch Admin throws ConcurrentModificationException after every execution

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

As I get deeper into it, I find I love the spring batch admin application.

However, after every job execution I see this exception being thrown.

**Environment**

```
OS: Windows 7
Java: jdk 1.8.0_25
Spring Batch Admin Sample version: 1.3.1
Spring version: 3.2.13   * stock 3.2.9 has a bug that causes other symptoms 
Spring-batch version: 3.0.2
Pivotal tc version:  3.0 Developer Edition
IDE: STS 3.6.3
```

**Log Snip:**

```
14:33:36.246 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:865) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.batch.admin.service.SimpleJobService.removeInactiveExecutions(SimpleJobService.java:498) ~[spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.1.MAXIS-MOD.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor196.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64) ~[spring-context-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53) ~[spring-context-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

My code doesn't touch the core of spring batch admin, so I'm a bit bewildered.

This is not a showstopper (yet), so I am open to suggestions (including eventually contributing a patch).

Comment: Are you using the map job repository?

Comment: I am using a database job repository.  The database is (in development only) being addressed across a VPN.

I also see sluggishness when opening the executions page.  Could the two be related?  If so, I will tag this for inclusion in my performance research.

Comment: db2 9.7 on Windows Server 2008 SP 1

Comment: I must add that we are using a bitronix JTA transaction manager with this configuration, because the nature of the work requires transactioning across multiple independent and (potentially) dissimilar databases.

Comment: @MichaelMinella  The performance issues go away when I am running the app on the server with the database, which is not a surprise (prior experience using DB2 over a WAN), but I still see the concurrent modification exception.  I haven't seen any ill effects from the exception, which is probably because my application under the framework is not that busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the exception is a buggy implementation of `org.springframework.batch.admin.service.SimpleJobService`, at least in 1.3.1.RELEASE:

```
private Collection<JobExecution> activeExecutions = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<JobExecution>());


public void removeInactiveExecutions() {
            for (Iterator<JobExecution> iterator = activeExecutions.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                JobExecution jobExecution = iterator.next();
    ...
                if (!jobExecution.isRunning()) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
```

Calling `iterator.getNext();` AFTER a previous call to `iterator.remove();` on a `java.util.ArrayList` - even synchronized - is not a good idea...

I am currently overriding the Spring Batch Admin configuration, using my own implementation of JobService for bean with id="jobService":

```
META-INF\spring\batch\override\execution-context.xml

...
<bean id="jobService" class="com.foo.springbatch.MyPatchedSimpleJobServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
    <property name="jobLocator" ref="jobRegistry" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered this issue and a simple fix is to go and change the code in org.springframework.batch.admin.service.SimpleJobService to:

```
public void removeInactiveExecutions() {
        **synchronized (activeExecutions) {**
            for (Iterator<JobExecution> iterator = activeExecutions.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                JobExecution jobExecution = iterator.next();
                try {
                    jobExecution = getJobExecution(jobExecution.getId());
                }
                catch (NoSuchJobExecutionException e) {
                    logger.error("Unexpected exception loading JobExecution", e);
                }
                if (!jobExecution.isRunning()) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        **}**
    }
```

Note ** above denotes the changes..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why is the answer accepted. It is not correct. The call of next() is after hasNext() of course. It is correct. A synchronization is missing to prevent possible clash of two or more scheduled calls of this method and also other modifications of the collection somewhere else in the class. The Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList .. as they have it, is not enough.

Comment: this was accepted as correct because it pointed out that the issue was a buggy spring class that needed to be worked around. I used a different workaround (or possibly ignored the exception, can't remember now). That product no longer uses the spring-batch admin GUI so I haven't worried about it in a long time.